Facing issue while using Conversable Agent Autogen
This is the Conversable Agent function:
def create_scoring_agent() -> ConversableAgent:
    """Creates an LLM-powered agent for extracting food and service scores from reviews."""
    scoring_agent_system_message = """
    You are an assistant that evaluates restaurant reviews. Your task is to:
    1. Identify adjectives describing food and customer service in the review.
    2. Assign scores based on the following rules:
       - Score 1: awful, horrible, disgusting
       - Score 2: bad, unpleasant, offensive
       - Score 3: average, uninspiring, forgettable
       - Score 4: good, enjoyable, satisfying
       - Score 5: awesome, incredible, amazing
    Return the result as a JSON object with "food_score" and "service_score".
    Example:
    Review: "The food was average, but the customer service was unpleasant."
    Output: {"food_score": 3, "service_score": 2}
    """
    return ConversableAgent(
        name="scoring_agent",
        system_message=scoring_agent_system_message,
        llm_config={
            "config_list": [
                {
                    "model": "gpt-4o-mini", 
                    "api_key": os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY")  # Fetch API key from environment variable
                }
            ]
        }
    )

def analyze_reviews_with_agent(reviews: List[str]) -> Dict[str, List[int]]:
    """Uses an agent to analyze reviews and extract scores."""
    agent = create_scoring_agent()
    food_scores, service_scores = [], []

    for review in reviews:
        # Send the review to the agent for scoring
        user_message = f"Analyze this review: '{review}'. Extract food_score and service_score."
        print(user_message)
        **response = agent.initiate_chat([{"role": "user", "content": user_message}])**
        print(response)

        # Parse the agent's response
        try:
            result = eval(response["content"])  # Convert string to dictionary
            food_scores.append(result["food_score"])
            service_scores.append(result["service_score"])
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error processing review: {review}. Error: {e}")

    return {"food_scores": food_scores, "customer_service_scores": service_scores}


Error:
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'list' object has no attribute '_raise_exception_on_async_reply_functions'
File "/Users/shubham.gaur/Documents/Assignments/llm-agents/lab01_release/main.py", line 113, in analyze_reviews_with_agent
response = agent.initiate_chat([{"role": "user", "content": user_message}])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/shubham.gaur/Documents/Assignments/llm-agents/lab01_release/main.py", line 156, in main
scores = analyze_reviews_with_agent(reviews.get(user_query, []))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/shubham.gaur/Documents/Assignments/llm-agents/lab01_release/main.py", line 172, in 
main(sys.argv[1])
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_raise_exception_on_async_reply_functions'


I was just initiating the agent chat so that it calls the gpt given the prompt.
For a better gist have a look at the screenshot. fails in the analyze_reviews_with_agent function.


Did you check the documentation for that function? https://microsoft.github.io/autogen/0.2/docs/reference/agentchat/conversable_agent/#initiate_chat What you’ve posted seems completely incompatible with what that function expects to see.

When an LLM Agent starts interacting with other agents in the AutoGen framework, there must be other agents present. According to the AutoGen docs, the initiate_chat method requires at least one recipient, which should be an instance of ConversableAgent. Additionally, it is good to specify the message, max_turns, and summary_method arguments.
Here is an example of the sequential conversation pattern in AutoGen, which I assume is the one you intended to use:
import os
from autogen import ConversableAgent

llm_config = {"config_list": [{"model": "gpt-4o-mini", "api_key": os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY")}]}
# the main entrypoint/supervisor agent
entrypoint_agent = ConversableAgent("entrypoint_agent", 
                                        system_message=entrypoint_agent_system_message, 
                                        llm_config=llm_config)
# other agents
data_fetch_agent = ConversableAgent("data_fetch_agent", 
                                      system_message=data_fetch_agent_system_message, 
                                        llm_config=llm_config)
review_analysis_agent = ConversableAgent("review_analysis_agent", 
                                        system_message=review_analysis_agent_system_message, 
                                        llm_config=llm_config)
scoring_agent = ConversableAgent("scoring_agent", 
                                        system_message=scoring_agent_system_message, 
                                        llm_config=llm_config)

result = entrypoint_agent.initiate_chats(
        [
            {
                "recipient": data_fetch_agent,
                "message": f"The question is: {user_query}",
                "max_turns": 2,
                "summary_method": "last_msg",
            },
            {
                "recipient": review_analysis_agent,
                "message": "These are the reviews",
                "max_turns": 1,
                "summary_method": "reflection_with_llm",
                "summary_args": {"summary_prompt":"some prompt"},
            },
            {
                "recipient": scoring_agent,
                "message": "These are raw scores",
                "max_turns": 2,
                "summary_method": "last_msg",
            },
        ]
    )

